# array construction in python

Tags: python, numpy

Assume we have an array of length `1000` where all of its values are `1`, i.e., it is like `[1,1,1,1,1,1,…,1,1,1,1]`. Now suppose we need to convert this array to a block array such that `25%` of the array would be **block of** `0` instead of `1` located **uniformly at random positions**. Therefore, the final array would be something like `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,…,1,1,1,0,0,0]`.

Is there any efficient way in python/numpy to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by a "block array"?

Comment: Too many variables to consider.  Can you control how large this block of zeroes is?  Also, consider `[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]`.  You can consider that as either 3 blocks of 2 zeroes together, 1 block of 6 zeroes, or 2 blocks of 3 zeroes.  As such, would this be counted as 1, 2, or 3 blocks of zeroes?

Comment: @MarkDickinson : By block array I mean that instead of having individual `0` and `1` following each other, we have blocks of `0`s followed by blocks of  `1`.

Comment: @rayryeng : assume that block of zeros have constant length which we know. Also, assume that two `0` blocks should not be adjacent.

Comment: @Alfredo - Would this be 25% of the array consisting of zeroes, or 25% of the array consisting of **blocks** of zeroes?  This distinction is important.

Comment: @rayryeng : assume blocks of `0`s consist 25% of the whole array.

Comment: @Alfredo - Never mind.  Someone answered.  Good luck!

Comment: Should the zeros constitute *exactly* 25% of the total array, or is that allowed to vary with the randomness?

Comment: @MarkDickinson : Exactly 25%.

Comment: Exactly may not work for some scenarios. Take for example an array of length 1000. 25% is 250 and so you desire 250 zeroes exactly. However, if you choose a block length that doesn't evenly divide into 250 then you won't get it exactly. Take for example a block length of 3. 3 does not divide 250 evenly and so you won't get 25% to be zeroes in your array exactly. You should probably edit your post to account for cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create random indices list with the length of `0.25` main list then change that indices in main list to 0.

```
>>> l=np.ones(30)
>>> length=len(l)
>>> rand=np.arange(int(0.25*length))
>>> np.random.shuffle(rand)
>>> l[rand]=0
>>> l
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

And more precise you can do :

```
main_list[np.random.choice(length,int(0.25*length),replace=False)]=0
```

Comment: `randint` chooses indices with replacement; you'll get indices chosen twice if you do this.

Comment: Also, this doesn't really handle the "block" thing.

Comment: @Kasra: `rand` is an array of indices, but there's nothing guaranteeing that all those indices are distinct.  Try it for yourself on an array of size 1000: you'll likely end up with *fewer* than 250 zeros because of repeated indices.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Aha, thank you so much for mentioning this point.that foolish mistake makes all of my code wrong! I just had a miss understanding about `replace`! as  user2357112 said!

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry I didn't get what you mean! fortunately  Mark Dickinson  make it clear for me! and about the blocks OP doesn't mentioned anything about the blocks like the length or ... . and due to accepting the answer seems that is not important for him! although this answer gives the blocks but with length 1 ;)

Comment: You might want to test your revised code and see what it does; it has several errors preventing it from working correctly.